# Verification of user's existence in chat script

Tags: javascript, chat

When ever user leaves chat page (Either by logging out or just by simple closing the browser window). Chat script instantly detects that user left and show offline sign. This process takes place in few seconds how this really works?

I am an ASP.NET/c# developer apart from it I use JavaScripts and rarely PHP. Please don't exceed answer(s) to other languages.

Comment: Look into long-polling as well.

Comment: @Prisoner - Great answer! hope it helps me. Gimme a day. I will try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have your JavaScript chat code send a message to the server every 2 seconds using XMLHttpRequest. When you don't receive a message, that means that the user has closed the window.

Comment: Is `XMLHttpRequest` works that much faster to verify for every 2 seconds and can it with stain even when chat server is loaded with millions of users at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

As promised, here are some classes used in implementing long-polling.  There are basically 6 classes (see below).  Some of these classes may end-up being unneeded for YOUR purposes, but they made sense for mine.  These have "mostly" been sanitized for you.

1. **Controller**: Processes actions required to create a valid response (db operations etc.)
2. **Processor**: Manages asynch communication with the web page (itself)
3. **IAsynchProcessor**: The service processes instances that implement this interface
4. **Sevice**: Processes request objects that implement IAsynchProcessor
5. **Request**: The IAsynchProcessor wrapper containing your response (object)
6. **Response**: Contains custom objects or fields

If you need help with the JavaScript or HTML add-in a comment below...I will write something for you.

**HTTP HANDLERS:**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace Concept.LongPolling.Handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Controller
    /// </summary>
    public class Controller : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTORS
        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES

        /// <summary>Gets a Boolean value indicating that another request can use the current instance of the DefaultHttpHandler class.</summary>
        /// <remarks>Returning true makes the same AsyncHttpHandler object be used for all requests.</remarks>
        /// <remarks>Returning false here makes ASP.Net create object per request.</remarks>
        public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

        #endregion

        #region METHODS

        /// <summary>Enables synchronous processing of HTTP Web requests</summary>
        /// <param name="context">An HttpContext object that provides references to the intrinsic server objects</param>
        /// /// <remarks>This is where you would send commands to the controller that would affect processing in some manner.</remarks>
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>Creates the response object which is serialized back to the client</summary>
        /// <param name="response"></param>
        public static Response CreateResponse(Response response)
        {
            try
            {
                response.Generate();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                response.SessionValid = false;
            }

            return response;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using Concept.LongPolling.LongPolling;

namespace Concept.LongPolling.Handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Processor
    /// </summary>
    public class Processor : IHttpHandler, IHttpAsyncHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTORS
        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES

        /// <summary>Gets a Boolean value indicating that another request can use the current instance of the DefaultHttpHandler class.</summary>
        /// <remarks>Returning true makes the same AsyncHttpHandler object be used for all requests.</remarks>
        /// <remarks>Returning false here makes ASP.Net create object per request.</remarks>
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

        #endregion

        #region METHODS

        /// <summary>Enables synchronous processing of HTTP Web requests</summary>
        /// <param name="context">An HttpContext object that provides references to the intrinsic server objects</param>
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region IHttpAsyncHandler Members

        /// <summary>Enables asynchronous processing of HTTP Web requests</summary>
        /// <param name="context">An HttpContext object that provides references to the intrinsic server objects</param>
        /// <param name="cb">The method to call when the asynchronous method call is complete. If callback is null, the delegate is not called.</param>
        /// <param name="extraData"></param>
        /// <returns>Any state data that is needed to process the request.</returns>
        public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
        {
            Int32 someValueYouLikeToSendInYourClass = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["Number"]);

            Request request = new Request(cb, context);
            request.Response.Number = someValueYouLikeToSendInYourClass;

            Service.Singleton.AddRequest(request);

            return request;
        }

        /// <summary>Provides an end method for an asynchronous process.</summary>
        /// <param name="result">An object that contains information about the status of the process.</param>
        public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            Request request = result as Request;
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            request.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
            request.HttpContext.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(request.Response));
            request.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**SUPPORTING CLASSES:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Concept.LongPolling.LongPolling
{
    /// <summary>Represents the executable instance of an asynchronous operation.</summary>
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IAsynchProcessor : IAsyncResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value that indicates whether the operation completed sucessfully.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>true if the operation completed sucessfully; otherwise, false.</returns>
        bool ProcessRequest();
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;

namespace Concept.LongPolling.LongPolling
{
    public class Service
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTORS

        private Service()
        {
            requests = new List<IAsynchProcessor>();
            backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainLoop));
            backgroundThread.IsBackground = true;
            backgroundThread.Start();
        }

        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES

        static readonly object _padlock = new object();

        private static Service singleton;
        private Thread backgroundThread;
        private List<IAsynchProcessor> requests;

        public static Service Singleton
        {
            get
            {
                lock (_padlock)
                {
                    if (_singleton == null)
                        _singleton = new Service();
                    return _singleton;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region METHODS

        private void MainLoop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                foreach (IAsynchProcessor request in requests.ToArray())
                {
                    if (request.ProcessRequest())
                        requests.Remove(request);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        public void AddRequest(IAsynchProcessor request)
        {
            requests.Add(request);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Concept.LongPolling.Business;
using System.Data;

namespace Concept.LongPolling.Handlers
{
    public class Response
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTORS

        public Response()
        {
            SessionValid = true;
            Exception = String.Empty;
        }

        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES

        public const int TimeOffset = 120;

        public Int32 Number { get; set; }
        public bool SessionValid { get; set; }
        public String Exception { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region METHODS

        public void Generate()
        {
            // do some desired operation
            Number += 1;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Concept.LongPolling.LongPolling;

namespace Concept.LongPolling.Handlers
{
    public class Request : IAsynchProcessor
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTORS

        public Request(AsyncCallback callback, HttpContext context)
        {
            asyncCallback = callback;
            httpContext = context;
            createdTime = DateTime.Now;

            Response = new Response();
        }

        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES

        public const int TimeoutSeconds = 15;

        private AsyncCallback asyncCallback;
        private HttpContext httpContext;
        private DateTime createdTime;

        public bool TimedOut
        {
            get
            {
                return ((DateTime.Now - createdTime).TotalSeconds >= TimeoutSeconds);
            }
        }

        public Response Response { get; set; }

        #region IAsyncResult Members

        public HttpContext HttpContext
        {
            get
            {
                return httpContext;
            }
        }
        public object AsyncState { get; set; }

        System.Threading.WaitHandle IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        bool IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return isCompleted; }
            set
            {
                if (!value) return;

                this.isCompleted = true;
                asyncCallback(this);
            }
        }
        bool isCompleted = false;

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region METHODS

        public bool ProcessRequest()
        {
            this.Response = Controller.CreateResponse(this.Response);
            this.IsCompleted = true;

            return this.IsCompleted;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The chat can send a logout message using the `onunload` event, which is triggered if the user leaves the page/closes the browser, however it is not reliable. A second option for the server is to begin a timeout countdown as soon as the underlying TCP connection is closed and show the user as "offline" in case he does not reconnect in time.